# ValueError: Location values cannot contain NaNs, got: [nan, nan]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

```
import folium
import pandas

data= pandas.read_csv("maps.txt")

lat = list(data["latitude"])
lon = list(data["longitude"])

map= folium.Map(location=[31.5204, 74.3587], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")

for lt, ln in zip(lat, lon):
    c1 = fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lt, ln], popup="Hi i am a Country",icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))

child = fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[31.5204, 74.5387], popup="Welcome to Lahore", icon= folium.Icon(color='green')))

map.add_child(fg)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\check2.py", line 14, in 
    c1 = fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lt, ln], popup="Hi i am a Country",icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\folium\map.py", line 647, in __init__
    self.location = _validate_coordinates(location)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\folium\utilities.py", line 48, in _validate_coordinates
    'got:\n{!r}'.format(coordinates))
ValueError: Location values cannot contain NaNs, got:
[nan, nan]
```

```
map.save("Lahore.html")
```

Actually i was making markerss of the map using txt file (commas separated) it opened successfully but i wanted all those adresses of countries to become markers and when i tried it just gave this error.

Comment: provide some details like what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually i was making a map all the details were in the text file (commas separated)

Comment: and when i tried to make all the information in csv to the map in form of markers this error occurred

Comment: Edit your question to add details.

Comment: Just did, Sorry actually I am new here. So, don't know much...

Comment: Then this might help you [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks I checked!

Answer (score 3):

You have NA's in your dataset somewhere.  Drop those rows before plotting:

```
data=data.dropna(subset=['longitude'])

data=data.dropna(subset=['latitude'])
```

That will drop the bad rows. You could also put a print statement in your plotting loop in order to ID which list elements are causing the issue and then go and fix it:

```
print(lt, ln)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `data[data.isnull()]` . You would see that you might be having entries in the dataframe which are empty or `NaN` values as per pandas.

You would want to fix that.

Comment: Did you got any result while executing `data[data.isnull()]` ?

Answer (score 0):

check the CSV file and make sure missing long, lati data or, make sure you don't have data corresponding to Nan columns which have data corresponding to other columns. My problem was with excel, so when I made a fix with the data error vanished.