# Python folium - ValueError: Location values cannot contain NANs

Tags: python, folium

I have a problem.
After fetching my .csv file in Python I keep getting the following error:

**ValueError: Location values cannot contain NANs**.

My code looks like this:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("surveyed.csv")
 fc=folium.FeatureGroup(name="Tbs",overlay=True)
 cf_survey_cluster = MarkerCluster(name="Tbs").add_to(map)
 for i,row in df.iterrows():
  city = df.at[i,'City']
  address = df.at[i,'Address']
  postcode = df.at[i,'Post Code']
  dead = df.at[i,'Deadline']
  lat = df.at[i, 'Latitude']
  lng = df.at[i, 'Longitude']

      popup = '<b>CITY: </b>' + str(city) + '<br>' + '<b>ADDRESS: </b>' + str(address) + ', ' + str(postcode) + '<br>' + '<b>DEADLINE: </b>' + str(dead)

      cf_survey_marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng], popup=popup, icon = folium.Icon(color='green', icon='glyphicon-calendar'))
```

My .csv file is fine, no gaps seen at all.

I tried the following query:

[ValueError: Location values cannot contain NaNs, got: [nan, nan]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621361/valueerror-location-values-cannot-contain-nans-got-nan-nan)

but I don't know how to provide the `isnull` option to my code. I tried:

```
    lat = df[df.isnull(at[i, 'Latitude'])]
```

but now the error shows:

**The value at is not defined.**

Is there any chance to make it fixed?

**UPDATE:**

This approach also doesn't work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("surveyed.csv")
fc=folium.FeatureGroup(name="To be surveyed",overlay=True)
cf_survey_cluster = MarkerCluster(name="To be surveyed").add_to(map)
for i,row in df.iterrows():
 city = df.at[i,'City']
 address = df.at[i,'Address']
 postcode = df.at[i,'Post Code']
 dead = df.at[i,'Deadline']
 #lat = df.at[i, 'Latitude']
 #lng = df.at[i, 'Longitude']
 latlon = df.dropna(subset=['Longitude','Latitude'])

 popup = '<b>CITY: </b>' + str(city) + '<br>' + '<b>ADDRESS: </b>' + 
 str(address) + ', ' + str(postcode) + '<br>' + '<b>DEADLINE: </b>' + 
 str(dead)

 cf_survey_marker = folium.Marker(location=[latlon], popup=popup, icon = folium.Icon(color='green', icon='glyphicon-calendar'))
```

as I get an error:

**ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got: [                City                              Address  ...   Latitude Longitude**

[image]

Comment: See updated answer. Without your CSV, I can't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dropna() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove nan values from columns.

```
df.dropna(axis='columns')
```

Example:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Longitude','Latitude'])
```

```
df = pd.read_csv("surveyed.csv")
df = df.dropna(subset=['Longitude','Latitude'])

fc=folium.FeatureGroup(name="To be surveyed",overlay=True)
cf_survey_cluster = MarkerCluster(name="To be surveyed").add_to(map)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
 city = df.at[i,'City']
 address = df.at[i,'Address']
 postcode = df.at[i,'Post Code']
 dead = df.at[i,'Deadline']
 lat = df.at[i, 'Latitude']
 lng = df.at[i, 'Longitude']


 popup = '<b>CITY: </b>' + str(city) + '<br>' + '<b>ADDRESS: </b>' + 
 str(address) + ', ' + str(postcode) + '<br>' + '<b>DEADLINE: </b>' + 
 str(dead)

 cf_survey_marker = folium.Marker(location=[lat, lon], popup=popup, icon = folium.Icon(color='green', icon='glyphicon-calendar'))
```

Comment: How can I put it into my code?

Comment: Added example. Drop the NAN values before you do anything with the dataframe.

Comment: how does it correspond to  lat = df[df.isnull(at[i, 'Latitude'])]  ?

Comment: It doesn't. Comment that out and drop the nan using the dropna function before your for loop, right after your pd.read_csv.

Comment: it doesn't work. Instead I get
ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got:

Comment: Thanks for updating. Uncomment your lat / lon lines lat = df.at[i, 'Latitude'] and try again. AND, you need to latlon = df.dropna(subset=['Longitude','Latitude']) right after you read the CSV into the dataframe, not in the for loop.

Comment: It's not latlon = df.dropna(subset=['Longitude','Latitude']) , it's df = ...you need to drop NAN from the lat, lon columns in the DF as the df is what you loop through not latlon.

Comment: Now is PERFECT! This is exactly what I was looking for - not only the solution but the advise with respect of the code placement! Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to hear it. Cheers.